# IBM Bluemix Containers : cf ic stats not working

Tags: docker, statistics, containers, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to get the command `cf ic stats` working but whenever I run it, it just returns 0s for all the datapoints:

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE/LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O
TestNode            0.00%               0 B/0 B             0.00%               0 B/0 B
```

If I try to run the command with the option as listed in the docks for a single result `cf ic stats my_container --no-stream` it treats `--no-stream` as the name of a node.

The BlueMix Container docs list this command as supported. Is there a problem with it at the moment?

(Using IBM-Containers plugin v0.8.788) on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Just as described in the documentation:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__stats

The `--no-stream` parameter is prefixed to container's name:

`cf ic stats --no-stream my_container`. The example in that documentation is wrong.

Comment: I will have the documentation reviewed as a result of your answer. Thanks Simone!

Comment: Agreed. I did find that after more playing around. Unfortunately does not fix the underlying issue of the command not working

I would recommend removing it from the docs till its fixed